# Sympy __repr__ magic - How does it work?

Tags: python, sympy

I noticed that after calling `init_printing` method of sympy, variable's representation have a better visual appealing. I know that is usually done inheriting repr method.

But when I call `__repr__` method, result is different. Why?

Before `init_printing` being called, this is the result:

```
>>> import sympy as sy
>>> x = sy.Symbol('x')
>>> sy.exp(x)
exp(x)

>> sy.exp(x).__repr__()
'exp(x)'
```

After `init_printing` being called, this is the result:

```
>>> import sympy as sy
>> sy.init_printing()
>>> x = sy.Symbol('x')
>>> sy.exp(x)
 x
e

>> sy.exp(x).__repr__()
'exp(x)'
```

Why the **repr** method doesn't return the same as evaluating the representation of the variable?

```
>>> sy.exp(x).__repr__
<bound method Basic.__repr__ of exp(x)>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That function installs a custom [`sys.displayhook()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook), which is used in the interactive interpreter to echo the result of expressions:

> `sys.displayhook` is called on the result of evaluating an expression entered in an interactive Python session. The display of these values can be customized by assigning another one-argument function to `sys.displayhook`.

The implementation is found in the [`sympy.interactive.printing` module](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/9670ff89dd8bff7878c6d636ec4f493b87d092df/sympy/interactive/printing.py#L15-L33):

> ```
> def _init_python_printing(stringify_func, **settings):
>     """Setup printing in Python interactive session. """
>     import sys
>     from sympy.core.compatibility import builtins
>
>     def _displayhook(arg):
>         """Python's pretty-printer display hook.
>            This function was adapted from:
>             http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0217/
>         """
>         if arg is not None:
>             builtins._ = None
>             print(stringify_func(arg, **settings))
>             builtins._ = arg
>
> sys.displayhook = _displayhook
> ```

In other words, this has nothing to do with how the objects implement `__repr__`.

Comment: Didn't know about sys.displayhook existence. Thank you.